# What does this denotation mean? Ito Calculus

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

there are two denotations which I do not understand.
Please note that the two denotation are separate, $X$ in Denotation 1 has nothing related to $X$ in Denotation 2.

**Denotation 1:**
$$dX = 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
dt \\
dR 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$
Where:
$$ dR = \mu R dt + \sigma dB$$

**Denotation 2:**
$$dY = 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
dt\\
dX
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$
Where:
$$dX = \mu X dt + \sigma X dZ$$

For example in Denotation 1, if $dR$ alone, then I understand the drift and diffusion. But when $dX$ is expressed in form of matrix here, I am a little bit confuse. how to inteprete $dX$ (in Denotation 1) and $dY$ (in Denotation 2)
Thank you

Comment: I have no idea what this notation should mean, do you have the source where you found this?

Comment: Could it possibly mean that (taking the first case) the diffusion is $(0,\sigma)$ and the drift is $(1,\mu R)$?

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both notations

> **Denotation 1:**
> $$dX = 
> \begin{equation*}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> dt \\
> dR 
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{equation*}$$
> Where:
> $$ dR = \mu R dt + \sigma dB$$

they probably just meant it in vector notation $dX=[dX_{1},dX_{2}]$ and so eg. in notation 1 we have

$$dX_{1}=dt \text{ and }dX_{2}=dR=\mu R dt + \sigma dB.$$